# Why does quantitative easing negatively affect stocks?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, federal-reserve

Is there a solid rationale for why the Fed's quantitative easing negatively affects the stock markets? Is it because markets were due for a correction, and quantitative easing provided the excuse?

The Fed will stop purchasing government bonds, but the Fed is government, so what difference does it make?

Comment: With the exception of the Board of Governors in D.C., the regional Federal Reserve banks *aren't* government agencies. They're technically non-profit entities that banks are required to hold shares in. They're regulated by the Board, which in turn has federal oversight. Any profits they generate are returned to the Treasury. Also, is there evidence that QE is affecting the markets negatively? There may be market distortion, but I thought most of the criticism was that it was *inflating* the stock market, not affecting it negatively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you isolate the market impact to just the Fed's quantitative easing?  Can you rule out the future economic predictions of low growth and that there are reasons why the Fed has kept rates low and is trying its best to stimulate the economy?  Just something to consider here.

The key is to understand what is the greater picture here as well as the question of which stock market index are you looking at that has done so badly.  Some stocks may be down and others may be up so it isn't necessarily bad for all equally.

Comment: Well said. It's tempting for many people now to attribute everything they see wrong with the markets to the Fed, but most economists are skeptical of generalizations like that, to say the least.

Answer (score 5):

The stock market in general likes monetary easing. With lower interest rates and easy cheap money freely available, companies can borrow at reduced cost thus improving profits. As profits increase share prices generally follow. So as John Benson said Quantitative Easing usually has a positive effect on stocks.

The recent negativity in the stock markets was partly due to the possibility of QE ending and interest rates being raised in the future.

Comment: +1 In a word, *uncertainty* about the timing of the Fed's draw down of QE.